# Facebook login stopped working in my scringo android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, scringo

I have integrated facebook into my scringo android app and it was working fine previously.
Now suddenly without any code changes login/signup is not working.
So i updated both scingo sdk and facebook sdk but still no use,its not working.
do anyone know any changes happened to facebook sdk or for user perimissions or to scringo sdk..? please help me.